# How to get columns of a model instance in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, instance, static-methods, laravel-query-builder

Can I extract a specific column for a model instance in Laravel instead of using query methods statically? more clearly, instead of writing the code below:

```
MyModel::select('columnName')->where('id', $model->id)->first();
```

can we write?

```
$model->select('columnName');
```

Comment: Well, you have to do a query to get `$model`. Once you have a `$model`, though, you can just do `$model->columnName` - no need for additional queries.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you grab it from a model class, it is a Eloquent Object, and it has all attributes from the database.

But if you are talking about serializing that into an array or JSON everytime, then you need to modify your `$visible` array ;

if you wanna transform it for a specific case, then you need to do :

`MyModel::select('columnName')->where('id', $model->id)->first()->pluck('columnName');`